# Formatting Tooltip Value on Series

Tags: highcharts

I'm creating a multichart (line and column) and I need to format the tooltip value for only one of my series. The thing is: formatter doesn't seem to work inside series.

I have a point value like: 212575200

In tooltip it's being formatted into 2.125.752,00

But I need it to be formatted into: 2.1 M (for million)
(K for thousand, M for million, B for billion)

How can I format a tooltip value for only one of my series?

This is the code I'm using:

```
series : [{
            name : ((tipoGrafico == 'line' || tipoGrafico == 'column')?'ult':' '),
            data : dadosJson,
            pointStart: dadosJson[0][0],
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            yAxis: 0, // Em qual grafico do eixo Y irão esses dados
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: CASAS_DECIMAIS,
            }
        },{
            type: 'column',
            name: nomeEstudo,
            data: volume,
            pointStart: dadosJson[0][0],
            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            yAxis: 1,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: ((nomeEstudo != "neg") ? CASAS_DECIMAIS : 0),
                pointFormat: '<tspan style="color:{series.color}"> {series.name}: </tspan><tspan> ' + formatNumber(('{point.y}'/formataValores('{point.y}').divisor))+formataValores('{point.y}').letra + '</tspan>'
            },
        }],
```

Notice that I'm trying `pointFormat`, but It's returning a `NaN` from my other JS functions, because it can't figure out in time `'{point.y}'` is actually a `Number`, not a `String`.

Comment: If you have function to format that number then you need to use formatter, but use `tooltip.formatter` not `series[index].tooltip.formatter`. `pointFormat` doesn't allow functions, only simple patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following kind of function will help you:

```
tooltip:
{
formatter: function() {
for(var temp=0,tempLength = this.points.length;temp<tempLength; temp++)
{
//You will get the point value here by using following code
var Value = this.points[temp].y;
//Now you can apply any format to this value
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the formatter you can check which serie is displayed in the tooltip, then use condition (i.e based on the id of serie or name or index) and return content.

Comment: This was by far the simplest solution for me. Putting a formatter in each series map seems to get ignored so the solution was to put the formatter in the tooltip of the entire chart and check cases for each ID.